# Running an ASP app in IE with OpenLayers - tile requests getting redirected to ASP web server?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, http, openlayers

I'm currently developing an ASP application, which is running on an ASP.NET Development Server.

When I bring up a particular page in IE (it has an OpenLayers map on it), sometimes the tiles won't load. When this happens, I've noticed that opening another tab and going to the address of the tile (or even, say, Google) results in a standard "Server Error in '/MyApp' Application. // HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request // Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 9.0.0.0" page being displayed.

For some reason, it seems IE is directing the tile (or Google) web request to the ASP web server rather than the Internet at large. Any idea how I can stop this?

Update: This is definitely an IE issue. Although the app isn't written for Firefox, I've managed to load the page in question and there's no sign of the issue.

Update: As requested, here's the JS specifically for loading the map layer:

```
var npe = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
                "OS New Popular Edition (1940s)",
                "http://www.getmapping.com/iedirectimage/getmappingwms.aspx",
                { 'format': 'jpeg', 'layers': 'npeoocmap' },
                {
                    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700"),
                    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(0, 0, 800000, 1300000),
                    resolutions: new Array(1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000),
                    units: "m"
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the service that tiles are loaded from IS a ASP.NET application, so that's not strange you're getng ASP.NET error messages. I suspect it's some kind of proxy that is redirecting requests to some WMS service..

WMS service itself looks ok, so maybe those times you're not getting tiles there is no map data at locations where you pan/zoom?

Did you try to open exact same tile url in IE and Firefox?